# How to encode and segment at the same time?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-streaming

I want to implement HTTP streaming server, which is similar to this (http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/452/iphone-http-streaming-with-ffmpeg-and-an-open-source-segmenter/)
But, instead of segment the video file after it is completely converted by ffmpeg, I want to do encoding and segmenting at the same time (something like if the output stream from the encoder is sent to the segmenter immediately).

Thanks

lvreiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much what Air Video Server and other similar software are doing. I can't give you an exact solution here, but Air Video is using ffmpeg so it should be possible to make your own solution with ffmpeg as the basis. By looking at the processes while running live conversion on Air Video you will also get the parameters used. Maybe this can help you in the right direction :)